# How to set GPU/cpu frequency of Android as per my application use-performance vs power saving?

Tags: android, linux

Rather than setting cpu and GPU frequency manually using kernel manager, I want to make a script that will run when I open a particular app (say a heavy android game), and my desired GPU/cpu speed for that game, and the desired clock speed when I closed that app, also finally one desired state when my screen is off.

Answer (score 2):

I know a method that applies only when your device is rooted.

#### Set CPU frequencies:

Android devices usually apply big-little core architecture. For each mobile phone, you shall go to their official site to check their hardware parameters. Now, let's just assume that the sample phone has 4 little cores and 4 big cores. They are indexed as 0-7 (the first 4 are little ones and the others are big ones).

1. `cd /sys/devices/system/cpu`
2. - little cores: `echo userspace > cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor && echo ${freq} > cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_setspeed`
   - big cores: `echo userspace > cpu4/cpufreq/scaling_governor && echo ${freq} > cpu4/cpufreq/scaling_setspeed`

I also strongly suggest you google what is a `governor` and how the whole bunch of CPU frequency related interfaces works.

#### Set GPU frequencies:

The first thing to do is figuring out where the virtual device files are located:

`find / -name "available_governors" 2> /dev/null`

This might output a path like `/path/to/folder/available_governors`. Here we note `GPUDIR=/path/to/folder`.

Then we can set a static frequency just as what we want:

```
cd $GPUDIR
echo userspace > governor
echo $freq > userspace/set_freq
```

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth method to set the frequencies but is there any way i can make it application specific ? I am sure operating systems have this function inbuilt as in when to run at higher clock speeds while doing heavy tasks like gaming/hd video versus something like browsing.

Comment: I don't know. But I suspect the answer is no.